# Getting line numbers with `?` when using Box<dyn std::error::Error>

Tags: rust

This thread shows how to display the originating error line number for std::io::Error: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/getting-line-numbers-with-as-i-would-with-unwrap/47002/3. It it possible to get this to work with `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` instead? Basically, I want the following to work (using the same code snippet provided in the answer of the thread):

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), LocatedError<Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> {
    std::fs::File::open("blurb.txt")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

But I am not sure how to implement this for unsized errors.

Comment: The example you linked to has an implementation for `From<std::io::Error> for LocatedError<std::io::Error>` - the implementation for `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this eventually by removing the trait bound for `LocatedError` and implementing the `From<std::error::Error>` for `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct LocatedError<T> {
    inner: T,
    location: &'static Location<'static>
}

impl<E: Error + 'static> std::fmt::Display for LocatedError<E> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}, {}", self.inner, self.location)
    }
}

impl<E: Error + 'static> From<E> for LocatedError<Box<dyn Error>> {
    // The magic happens here
    #[track_caller]
    fn from(err: E) -> Self {
        return LocatedError { 
            inner: Box::new(err), 
            location: std::panic::Location::caller() 
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), LocatedError<Box<dyn Error>>> {
    std::fs::File::open("blurb.txt")?;
    Ok(())
}
```